# Postgres Procedures not working on AWS RDS Postgres Installation

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.5

I have following procedure

```
Create or replace procedure test_data (user_id character varying, out ob_success_flag Boolean) IS
Declare
Begin
If (user_id is not null) then
  Ob_success_flag = true;
Else
  Ob_success_flag = false;
End if;
  End;
Commit;
```

working on self hosted installation of PostgreSQL server 9.5

But, when I created an instance server using AWS RDS PostgreSQL, following procedure doesn't work.

It shows error near  `procedure`

Using same pgAdmin Client while connecting to both instances.

Comment: Postgres 9.1 doesn't have procedures. I don't see how it can work on 9.1 as procedures were introduced in PG 11. Whether a procedure would work in AWS PG depends on the version there. Also your syntax for creating it is incorrect.

Comment: @404 my mistake, using 9.5 . Just confirmed the versions again.

Comment: As 404 already wrote: stored procedures were introduced in Postgres 11 - Postgres 9.5 won't work either

Comment: Sorry, my mistake the local installation was of Edb 9.5 not postgre 9.5 `https://www.enterprisedb.com/`. Its also built over postgre which created some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql does not allow out parameters in procedures as far as I know.  Inout parameters are allowed though.
This should make a valid plpgsql procedure:

```
create or replace procedure test_data (user_id character varying, inout ob_success_flag boolean) 
as $$
Begin
If (user_id is not null) then
  Ob_success_flag = true;
Else
  Ob_success_flag = false;
End if;
End;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Best regards,
Bjarni